# Reorder a column in a dataframe to a specified order

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame, where every row has a value, and every block of 100 rows has an index (between 1 and 10). I would like to sort the index blocks in a particular order, but am unsure how to do that:

```
N=1000
value = runif(N, min=0, max=100)
index = rep(1:10, each=100)
DF=data.frame(value,index)
ord = c(1,4,6,3,7,9,8,2,5,10)
```

So basically, I would like the index column of DF to be ordered in blocks of the order specified in ord, instead of the index column of DF being ordered as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: When making up data, try to limit it to only what you need. 20 cases in blocks of 2 would be just as sufficient as 1000 cases in blocks of 100.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply convert `index` to factor and set the levels as in `ord` order and then sort the data as in

```
DF$index <- factor(DF$index, levels = ord)
DF[order(DF$index), ]
```

If you don't want to "*alter your original data*" you could simply create a separate index as in

```
indx <- factor(DF$index, levels = ord) 
DF[order(indx), ]
```

Additional otion is to order your data set by reference using `setorder` from the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setorder(setDT(DF)[, index := factor(index, levels = ord)], index)
```

Comment: I would also do this way

Answer (score 2):

Here is my proposal:

```
#Genreate the data    
N<-1000
value <- runif(N, min=0, max=100)
index <- rep(1:10, each=100)
DF<-data.frame(value,index)
ord <- c(1,4,6,3,7,9,8,2,5,10)

#Create a list with the data sorted by the provided order
newDF<-apply(matrix(ord,,ncol=1),1,function(x) DF[DF[,2]==x,])

#Unlist the list into a dataframe
do.call(rbind.data.frame,newDF)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without altering your original data, you can use `merge` with `sort=FALSE`:

```
merge(data.frame(index=ord), DF, by="index", sort=FALSE)

#   ord    value
#1    1 37.29915
#2    1 30.09436
#3    4 18.05961
#4    4 46.73024
#5    6 93.15545
#6    6 69.33484
#7    3 70.92353
#8    3 81.63010
#9    7 22.23649
#10   7 32.36390
# etc etc
```

Comment: Is *Without altering your original data* is referring to my answer? You know I could just do `indx <- factor(DF$index, levels = ord) ; DF[order(indx), ]`, right :) ? Nice solution though.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - 'Twas, though no disrespect intended :-P