# Sort dataframe group according to a target vector in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe such as shown below (original data is really big). I want to sort them based on the group of target vector and get the result.

dataframe

```
sample     group    
A           AA 
B           CC
C           CC
D           BB
E           AA
F           AA

target.vector <- c("AA", "BB", "CC")
```

result

```
 sample     group    
    A           AA 
    E           AA
    F           AA
    D           BB
    B           CC
    C           CC
```

Comment: If you just want to make `group` alphabetical, `df[order(df$group), ]`

Comment: @alistaire No I need to use the `target.vector`. It has some weird characters as well. Also, It has to be in the specific order as `target.vector`.

Comment: It's a little counterintuitive because `FALSE` comes before `TRUE` in sorting, but `df[do.call(order, lapply(target.vector, \`!=\`, df$group)), ]`

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447991/reorder-a-column-in-a-dataframe-to-a-specified-order/28448290

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could turn `group` into a `factor` and then use `order` e.g. for your sample data

```
...
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels=c('AA', 'CC', 'BB'))
df[order(df$group), ]
```

would result in

```
  sample group
1      A    AA
5      E    AA
6      F    AA
2      B    CC
3      C    CC
4      D    BB
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', set the `key` as 'group' and join with the 'target.vector'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, key = "group")[target.vector]
#     sample group
#1:      A    AA
#2:      E    AA
#3:      F    AA
#4:      D    BB
#5:      B    CC
#6:      C    CC
```

Changing the 'target.vector' does change the order

```
target.vector <- c("BB", "AA", "CC")
setDT(df1, key = "group")[target.vector]
#   sample group
#1:      D    BB
#2:      A    AA
#3:      E    AA
#4:      F    AA
#5:      B    CC
#6:      C    CC
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be `match`

```
df1[with(df1, order(match(group, target.vector))),]
#   sample group
#1      A    AA
#2      E    AA
#3      F    AA
#4      D    BB
#5      B    CC
#6      C    CC
```